# Pinescript to check if condition first becomes true and holds within n bars?

Tags: function, count, conditional-statements, pine-script

I want to create a function to check if a condition first becomes true anywhere within a history of n bars, and if it does return true for the first bar and return true for every subsequent bar within the range where the condition held true without breaking the series of trues since the first. I understand barssince may work for this but causes repainting so not an option for me.

e.g if n = 0 bars the function is only true when the condition is true on the current bar but not the bar immediately previous n + 1. If instead the function input is n > 0 bars, for the function to return true the condition must become true somewhere m within n history of bars, but false for m + 1, and any bar after m within n history forming a series of unbroken true conditions the function will also return true.

In this crude example where n = 4 for bars[3,2,1] the function would return true but if n = 2 no bars would be true because the condition first became true outside of n at bar[3]:

```
bars: 76543210
cond: 00001110
```

I am also interested in an alternate function version that would only return true if after the condition first becomes true, anywhere within n history, the condition must hold true until the current bar[0]. This version could only every return false for the previous example but would return true for any n <= 3 in this example:

```
bars: 76543210 
cond: 00001111
```

Some of my attempts to code this seem to check for one of these versions correctly but for some reason when I plot the output it is only marking the nth bar true when instead I would like it to mark all bars where the function was true within n history bars. If you can see the problem please let me know:

```
f_confirmCond(_n) =>
    for _i = 0 to _n
        _i == _n ? cond[_i] and not cond[_i+1] : cond[_i]


f_confirmCond(_n) =>
    for _i = 0 to _n
        if (not cond[_i])
            false
        else
            if (_i == _n)
                cond[_i] and not cond[_i + 1]
            else
                cond[_i]


f_confirmCond(_n) =>
     if (not cond[0])
         false
     else 
         for _i = 0 to _n
             if (_i == _n and (cond[_i] and not cond[_i + 1]))
                 for _i = 0 to _n
                     true
f_confirmCond(_n) =>
    _confirmCond = true
    _j = 0
    _found = false
    for _i = _n to 0
        if (_found == false and cond[_i] and not cond[_i+1])
            _found := true
        _confirmCond := _confirmCond and cond[_i] and (_found == false? not cond[_i+1] : true)
```